# Is it possible to create workflow in sharepoint to track individual users

Tags: workflow, promoted-links, user-tracking

I want to track individual users who have viewed items on a particular(two or three) promoted links list. Is there a way to do it with sharepoint workflow? If not, is there any other way to do it.

Comment: This is not possible with Workflow. You would have to use some kind of analytics to capture that. What version of Sharepoint your are using? Have you considered using Audit on the site to get that information?

Comment: @MarekSarad I am using sharepoint 2013. I tried looking into using Audit, however, I don't have an admin role or audit option available to me. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I can see 2 best options here Either enable Audit or have have custom Event Handler on the item. The Latter option is much more complex so I would recommend to check with your admins can they enable Audit settings.

Comment: how to create custom event handler?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? "Audit" is the correct answer. If you cannot access the "Audit" settings, then you definitely also can't deploy custom solutions.

Comment: @Nullldata, it's just that, bunch of other people later on would need this feature. They are going to assign users to watch videos listed on multiple promoted links list and would need to track these users to see if they have clicked on the link or not. So everyone needs to have "audit" setting enabled?

Comment: @user10 I think you don't understand what "Auditing" does. You don't turn it on for a user. You turn it on for a site collection - and then you are able to read specific logs later.

Comment: The problem with workflows (and event receivers in Visual Studio) is that they require an event (such as create item, or edit item) for them to do something.

SharePoint doesn't track the accessing of items (other than in auditing). IIS DOES track access though, although that is something else completely!

Comment: @Nullldata oh okay, make sense!! I am new to sharepoint so I am still learning about its features. Just so that I am not confused,  having "Auditing" enabled will allow any users to view who has clicked  what lists (eg. specific link of promoted list link) etc. right?

Comment: Yes. It also provides a lot of other information. I have included a new screenshot that shows the categories of information tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Workflows are not designed to "Track" users.

The problem with workflows (and event receivers in Visual Studio) is that they require an event (such as create item, or edit item) for them to do something.

In the picture below you can see the type of events that can trigger something (in an event receiver anyway)

[image]

**SharePoint doesn't track the accessing of items out of the box** (other than in Auditing, instructions below).

IIS DOES track access though, although that is something else completely!

You can instead use the Site Collection "Auditing" tools to track users in SharePoint.

[Check out this useful resource on the subject of "Auditing"](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2013/07/audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

You can find the settings in "Site Collection Administration".

If you do not have access to this, then you may need to speak to your SharePoint Site Collection Administrator.

[image: Settings]

[image: Auditing Options]